# Video embeds and thumbnails won't load on initial page visit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, embed

I have a few youtube videos that I've embedded into my site. The videos load and display fine once you refresh the page, but on the initial visit they only appear as black boxes. Here is the script I am using in the index.html file to replace my divs with the thumbnails and iframes once the react component is rendered

index.html

```js
       let youtube = document.querySelectorAll(".youtube");
    //now iterate through the selected items
    for (let i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {
      //thumbnail image source
      let source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed + "/sddefault.jpg";

      //load the image asynchronously
      let image = new Image();
        image.src = source;
        image.addEventListener("load", function() {
          youtube[i].appendChild(image);
        }.bind(this,i) );

      //attach click event to div and create iframe for it
      youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

          iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
          iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "");
          iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + 
 this.dataset.embed + "?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );
          this.innerHTML = "";
          this.appendChild(iframe);
      })
    }
```

react component that contains video mark-up:

```
<ArticleConsumer>
  {(stories) => {
       return stories.sports.map((story) => {
         var VIDEO_ID = story.videoPath.substring(32);
         var shortDate = story.date.substring(0, 10);
         return (
            /* Video wrapper */
            <div className="youtube" data-embed={VIDEO_ID}>
              {/* the play button */}
              <div className="play-button"></div>
            </div>
          )
        })
    }}
</ArticleConsumer>
```

Once again, the videos load and behave perfectly after you refresh the page, but they do not load upon the initial page visit. I've been struggling trying to figure out why

Comment: Hi, did you do anything to check that react app has finished rendering?

Comment: Yes, I checked the performance and network tabs on chrome and both indicated that the page had finished loading. I've been checking both of those tabs tirelessly to see what's the difference between the initial visit and when the page is refreshed, but I've found no answer yet.